# Creating custom data types with constraints

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create a custom data type. As an example

```
data Time  = Second Int deriving (Show)
```

However, this is too limiting (we could say later need milliseconds). I would like to instead define something like this:

```
data Time  = Second Num deriving (Show)
```

This doesn't compile because `Num` has kind `* -> ghc-prim-0.4.0.0:GHC.Prim.Constraint`

How do I setup `Time` such that `Second` may contain any `Num`?

Comment: Are you sure about having an arbitrary `Num`?  What if I did `Seconds (1 :+ 2)` after `import Data.Complex`?  Would it make sense to allow complex time?  Would it instead be better to have multiple constructors, so `data Time = Seconds Int | Milliseconds Int | Microseconds Int | Minute Int | Hour Int`?

Comment: Based on Mr F and Ben it seems the standard isn't to have any constraint (let alone Num).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a deprecated feature called Datatype Contexts that allows you to do that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
data Num a => Time a = Second a deriving (Show)
t = Second (5 :: Int)
main = print t
```

This executes on GHC 7.8.3 (sorry, don't have 7.10 to check), but warns you about the deprecation:

```
t.hs:1:14: Warning:
    -XDatatypeContexts is deprecated: It was widely considered a
misfeature, and has been removed from the Haskell language.
Second 5
```

A non-deprecated way to do it is to use [Generalized Algebraic Datatypes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Generalised_algebraic_datatype) (GADTs) (and you'll need standalone `deriving` as well):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, StandaloneDeriving #-}
data Time a where
    Second :: Num a => a -> Time a
deriving instance Show a => Show (Time a)
t = Second (5 :: Int)
main = print t
```

If you try to create a variable with something non-`Num`, you'll get a compilation error:

```
t = Second "a"

t.hs:12:5:
    No instance for (Num [Char]) arising from a use of ‘Second’
    In the expression: Second "a"
    In an equation for ‘t’: t = Second "a"
```

Comment: Thank you! :-)... now to understand GADTs ;-)

Comment: @GeneralBecos, GADTs are great, but I don't think this is such a great application of them.

Comment: Agreed. Mr F has given a good reason below on the why. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

One of the best examples of why this might not be so desirable is [found here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Other_uses) at the Wikibooks section on Classes and Types. They say:

> Type constraints in data declarations are less useful than it might seem at first. Consider:
>
> ```
> data (Num a) => Foo a = F1 a | F2 a String
> ```
>
> Here, Foo is a type with two constructors, both taking an argument of a type a which must be in Num. However, the (Num a) => constraint is only effective for the F1 and F2 constructors, and not for other functions involving Foo. Therefore, in the following example...
>
> ```
> fooSquared :: (Num a) => Foo a -> Foo a
> fooSquared (F1 x)   = F1 (x * x)
> fooSquared (F2 x s) = F2 (x * x) s
> ```
>
> ... even though the constructors ensure a will be some type in Num we can't avoid duplicating the constraint in the signature of fooSquared

This suggests that a reasonable option for you is to just create `Time` with a generic parameter, and then later ensure that the module functions that operate on `Time` data always have the necessary constraint for `Num`.

It won't be so much of a worry that someone goes off and foolishly makes `Time String` or something -- if they do, then none of the provided module functions are going to be helpful for them, so it doesn't matter so much.

There are also options to look up with GADTs, the `{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}` pragma, and the `{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}` pragma. But usually these start to rope in unnecessary degrees of extra complexity, especially if you're a Haskell novice like me.

Comment: Your suggestion of leaving the data type unconstrained is absolutely the standard way to do it. Someone might even have a use for a differently constrained version of the data type some day (e.g. it might make sense to work with times that are merely addable, or something). If you *do* need to constrain the data structure itself, then GADTs are the correct way to do it, but be aware that then every single `Time` value contains a `Num` instance so functions know which implementation of the `Num` functions to call.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to leave the type unconstrained.